# php. Ошибка в коде при обработке

Tags: php

```
$file = file("names.txt");
$search = "sdgdgdfg dgdfgdf";
$i = 0;
$k = '';
foreach($file as $v){
    if($v == $search) {
        $k = $i++;
        $j = $k + 5;//количество строк после искомого слова
    }
$i++;
}
while($k < $j) {
    echo $str_new[$k];
    $put .= "<a href='/$str_new[$k]'>$str_new[$k]</a>\n";
    $k++;
}
file_put_contents($put, $search);
```

Не пойму где ошибка (((
names.txt

```
sdf sdfsd
test
sdfsdf sgdf
sdgdgdfg dgdfgdf
test fgd
testdfg dgdfgdf
dgdfgdf
```

Помогите решить

Comment: Какая именно ошибка?

Comment: В том то и дело что пустой файл создается...

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: j in /var/www/d.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: put in /var/www/d.php on line 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как найти ошибку:

1. Включаем вывод ошибок
2. идём по адрессу https://translate.google.ru/ и вставляем текст ошибки, смотрим перевод.
3. Ага $j не определена
4. делаем `var_dump` перед `if` `var_dump($v == $search,$v,$search)`
5. ага не срабатывает почему?
6. Да потомучто блин в `$v` есть пробелы, переносы строки и д.р.
7. Тримем перед сравнением `if(trim($v) == trim($search))`
8. всё работает!